# I want to display the preview button after filling all the multistep form

Tags: javascript, html

here I have written a functionality for multistep form. Where I have written three different fieldset in a single form that means multistep form. So here my issue is I want to make a preview button after all form are filled. So before submitting the a form the user should able to view his data what user filled in all the form. So if any wrong information are entered so user can able to modify before submitting. So my issue is i want to display a preview button

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
  var opacity;

  $(".next").click(function() {

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

    //Add Class Active
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

    //show the next fieldset
    next_fs.show();
    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, {
      step: function(now) {
        // for making fielset appear animation
        opacity = 1 - now;

        current_fs.css({
          'display': 'none',
          'position': 'relative'
        });
        next_fs.css({
          'opacity': opacity
        });
      },
      duration: 600
    });
  });

  $(".previous").click(function() {

    current_fs = $(this).parent();
    previous_fs = $(this).parent().prev();

    //Remove class active
    $("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(current_fs)).removeClass("active");

    //show the previous fieldset
    previous_fs.show();

    //hide the current fieldset with style
    current_fs.animate({
      opacity: 0
    }, {
      step: function(now) {
        // for making fielset appear animation
        opacity = 1 - now;

        current_fs.css({
          'display': 'none',
          'position': 'relative'
        });
        previous_fs.css({
          'opacity': opacity
        });
      },
      duration: 600
    });
  });

  $('.radio-group .radio').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.radio').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
  });

  $(".submit").click(function() {
    return false;
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid" id="grad1">
  <div class="row justify-content-center mt-0">
    <div class="col-11 col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-6 text-center p-0 mt-3 mb-2">
      <div class="card px-0 pt-4 pb-0 mt-3 mb-3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 mx-0">
            <form id="msform">
              <!-- progressbar -->
              <ul id="progressbar">
                <li class="active" id="account"><strong>Post Ad</strong></li>
                <li id="personal"><strong>Personal</strong></li>
                <li id="payment"><strong>Payment</strong></li>
                <li id="confirm"><strong>confirm</strong></li>
              </ul>
              <!-- fieldsets -->
              <fieldset>
                <div class="form-card">
                  <h2 class="fs-title">Post Ad</h2>
                  <p><input type="text" placeholder="Search for your categories" name="type" maxlength="200" required="" id="id_post_type"></p>
                  <p><input placeholder="Title" type="text" name="title" maxlength="60" required="" id="id_post_title"></p>
                  <p><input type="number" placeholder="Price" name="price" step="any" required="" id="id_post_price"></p>
                  <p class="select_p"><input type="text" placeholder="Address" name="address" maxlength="100" required="" id="id_post_address">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="City" name="city" maxlength="50" required="" id="id_post_city"></p>
                  <p class="select_p"><input type="text" placeholder="State" name="state" maxlength="100" required="" id="id_post_state">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Zip" name="zip" maxlength="50" required="" id="id_post_zip"></p>
                </div>
                <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset>
                <div class="form-card">
                  <h2 class="fs-title">Automobiles Aircraft</h2>
                  <p><input type="text" placeholder="Mileage" name="mileage" maxlength="100" required="" id="id_post_mileage2">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Make" name="make" maxlength="50" required="" id="id_post_make"></p>
                  <p class="select_p">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Model" name="model" maxlength="100" required="" id="id_post_model">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Engine" name="engine" maxlength="50" required="" id="id_post_engine"></p>
                  <p class="select_p">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Drive Type" name="drive" required="" id="id_post_drive">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Year" name="year" required="" id="id_post_year2"></p>
                  <p class="select_p">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Location" name="location" required="" id="id_post_location2">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Exterior" name="exterior" required="" id="id_post_Exterior">
                  </p>
                  <p class="select_p">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Interior" name="interior" required="" id="id_post_Interior">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Fuel Type" name="fuel_type" required="" id="id_post_fuel_type"></p>
                  <p>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Transmission" name="transmission" required="" id="id_post_transmission</p>
    </div> <input type=" button " name="previous " class="previous action-button-previous " value="Previous " /> <input type="button " name="next " class="next action-button " value="Next Step " />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <div class="form-card ">
    <h2 class="fs-title ">Payment Information</h2>
    <div class="radio-group ">
    <div class='radio' data-value="credit "><img src="https://i.imgur.com/XzOzVHZ.jpg " width="200px " height="100px "></div>
    <div class='radio' data-value="paypal "><img src="https://i.imgur.com/jXjwZlj.jpg " width="200px " height="100px "></div> <br></div> <label class="pay ">Card Holder Name*</label> <input type="text " name="holdername " placeholder=" " />
    <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-9 "> <label class="pay ">Card Number*</label> <input type="text " name="cardno " placeholder=" " /> </div>
    <div class="col-3 "> <label class="pay ">CVC*</label> <input type="password " name="cvcpwd " placeholder="*** " /> </div></div>
    <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-3 "> <label class="pay ">Expiry Date*</label> </div>
    <div class="col-9 "> <select class="list-dt " id="month " name="expmonth ">
    <option selected>Month</option>
    <option>January</option>
    <option>February</option>
    </select> <select class="list-dt " id="year " name="expyear ">
    <option selected>Year</option></select> 
    </div>
    </div>
    </div> <input type="button " name="previous " class="previous action-button-previous " value="Previous " /> <input type="button " name="make_payment " class="next action-button " value="Confirm " />
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You're not really asking a concrete question Asad. Can you please be more specific? Where are you stuck?

Comment: So here my issue is I want to make a preview button after all form are filled. So before submitting the a form the user should able to view his data what user filled in all the form.

Answer (score 0):

The code below makes a function that makes you scroll to a given element

```
function scrollToElement(x){
  //this function receives an html element as its argument
  if(typeof x!="object"){return;} //test 1 to determine if it is a DOM element
  if(x.appendChild!=Document.prototype.appendChild){return;} //test 2 to determine if it is a DOM element
  scrollTo(x.left,x.top);
}
```

Basically, the preview can be to scroll right back to the data **instead of removing elements** to see the data one final time.. other than that ur code's pretty solid